# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException,org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Stacktrace:

> Error creating bean with name 'testBean': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'dao';  nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'dao.EmployeeDao' available:  expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.  Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

TestBean.java

```
package service;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import dao.EmployeeDao;

@Service
public class TestBean {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private EmployeeDao dao;

    public void m1() {
        int i=dao.updateEmp(77, 89);
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public void m2() {
        Map m=dao.findEmpById(12);
        System.out.println(m);  
    }

    public void m3() {
        List l=dao.findAllEmps();
        Iterator itr=l.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Map m=(Map) itr.next();
            System.out.println(m);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please format the code? Then you can ask your question like describe what are you trying to do? What is the problem you face?

Comment: Fromatted code. removed unnecessary code. added tags